# Converting WPF control to Mobile App( Xamarin.Foirm) in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, canvas

I am working on a Mobile App( Xamarin.Foirm). I have an WPF control that does animation that works, but now I am trying to convert it over to Mobile App( Xamarin.Frm) , so I can make a IOS, Android and UWP app that all  uses the same base library.

However, the base library does not have a canvas nor a , So how do I add my svg to it as a path ?

```
   <Viewbox>

        <Path   Name="path8"  Canvas.Left="83.948" Canvas.Top="89.126" Width="971.099"  Height="1047.555"  Stretch="Fill"  Fill="#FFE6F0FF" Data="M259.29 280.09c40.26-150 198.93-228.93 368.37-172.9c142.66 47.17 403.77 395 426 609.68     c21.09 203.81-200.17 404.81-536.78 418.9c-393.71 16.48-484.38-194.38-408.35-326.2C296 484.51 210.71 461 259.29 280.09z" d:IsLocked="True"/>
        <Canvas/>

        </Viewbox>

</ContentView.Content>
```

In visual Studios 2019 when you make an Mobile app (Xamarin.Forms) project you get 4 different projects. The 1st project is your base project( I do not know the real name for it) well it does not have a Canvas.

It does not have a path, viewbox nor canvas.
So how do I add my svgs and animation them, like I did with my WPF control?

Comment: use SkiaSharp for cross platform graphics

Comment: or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/shapes/path